# Generating sequential numbers encountered deadlock

Tags: java, db2, deadlock

We need to generate sequential numbers for our transactions. We encountered sqlcode=-911, sqlstate=40001, sqlerrmc=2 (deadlock) when concurrent users are trying to book transactions at the same time. Currently deadlock occurs because it is reading and updating to the same record. How can we design this so that deadlock can be prevented?

Comment: Please provide more info on what exactly cause the deadlock, what is the calling code, what is the db design? Currently there is nothing to go on.

Comment: The usual thing to do in that circumstance is just  to catch the exception and try again.  The alternative is to create transactions in a database table and let the database itself generate the primary key for it.

Comment: You can prevent from deadlock by using Synchronized Keyword. A synchronized block ensures that a call to a method that is a member of object occurs only after the current thread has successfully entered object’s monitor. Once a thread enters any synchronized method on an instance, no other thread can enter any other synchronized.

Answer (score 1):

Create a "seed" table that contains a single data row.
This "seed" table row holds the "Next Sequential" value.

When you wish to insert a new business data row using the "Next Sequential" value. perform the following steps.

1). Open a cursor for UPDATE on the "seed" table and fetch the current row. This gives you exclusive control over the seed value.
2). You will employ this fetched row as the "Next Value"... However before doing so
3). Increment the fetched "Next Value" and commit the update. This commit closes your cursor and releases the seed row with the new "Next Value".

you are now free to employ your "Next Value".

Comment: Other names you may have run into which describe this approach:  High-Water Mark, Sequence-ID Table, and Master Transaction Table.  ++Hector for the more efficient use of a dedicated table to the process.  Not sure a CURSOR is more efficient than a simple TRANSACTION boundary, but you could play with both to see what works in your environment.

Comment: Ive used the Cursor for update approach in many enterprise production systems. This approach queues requests for the "Next Value" in an orderly fashion, I have seen it support very high TPS 100's -> 1000's on mainframe z/OS DB2.

Comment: Very nice.  I think I'll add to my personal "extra time" to do list to try to run performance comparisons between the two techniques.  Because, well, knowing is nice, and playing is fun.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways around this issue, some less performant than others.

Deadlocks can be prevented if all objects are locked in the same hierarchical sequence.  [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock#Prevention]

However, solutions to the Dining Philosophers Problem [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem] which completely prevent deadlocks are often less performant than simply rolling back the transaction and retrying.  You'll need to test your solution.

If you're looking for a data-side solution, an old-fashioned (and potentially under-performant) approach is to force the acquisition of new transaction IDs to be atomic by establishing a rigorous lock sequence.

A quick-ish solution (test this under load before releasing to production!) could be to use `TRANSACTION` boundaries and have a *control row* acting as a gatekeeper.  Here's a stupid example which demonstrates the basic technique. 
 It has no error checking, and the code to reclaim ghost IDs is outside the scope of this example:

```
DECLARE @NewID INTEGER;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
UPDATE [TABLE] SET [LOCKFLAG] = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE [ROW_ID] = 0;
SELECT @NewID = MAX([ROW_ID])+1 FROM [TABLE];
INSERT INTO [TABLE] ([ROW_ID]) VALUES (@NewID);
UPDATE [TABLE] SET [LOCKFLAG] = NULL WHERE [ROW_ID] = 0;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

The idea is to make this atomic, single-threaded, serialized operation very, very short in duration -- do *only* what is needed to safely reserve the ID and get out of the way.

By making the first step to update row 0, if all ID requests comply with this standard, then competing users will simply queue up behind that first step.

Once you have your ID reserved, go off and do what you like, and you can use a new transaction to update the row you've created.

You'd need to cover cases where the later steps decide to `ROLLBACK`, as there would now be a ghost row in the table.  You'd want a way to reclaim those; a variety of simple solutions can be used.